# duda con la libreria basic player

Tags: java

hola que tal amigos estoy tratando de hacer un slider que se mueven por medio del tiempo que va recorriendo de la cancion pero no tengo idea de como hacer y que valor maximo tiene la cancion,la libreria usa estos metodos para todo eso pero no encuentro en ningun lado de como saber.

hice un cronometro que me va dando hora,minuto,segundos de la cancion por medio del metodo progress.
help me please :c

```
@Override                   
    public void opened(Object stream, Map properties) {
//stream  es la ruta de la cancion


  //properties imprime esto
  //  {mp3.copyright=false, mp3.framesize.bytes=1040, mp3.vbr=false, //mp3.framerate.fps=38.28125, vbr=false, bitrate=320000, mp3.channels=2, //audio.channels=2, audio.framerate.fps=38.28125, //basicplayer.sourcedataline=com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectSDL@//41aba873, mp3.bitrate.nominal.bps=320000, mp3.padding=false, //mp3.version.mpeg=1, mp3.crc=false, mp3.original=true, //mp3.frequency.hz=44100, //mp3.id3tag.v2=java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@781cdea9, mp3.vbr.scale=0, //mp3.version.encoding=MPEG1L3, audio.type=MP3, mp3.version.layer=3, //mp3.id3tag.v2.version=4, audio.samplerate.hz=44100.0, mp3.header.pos=138, //mp3.mode=1}


    }



        @Override
        public void progress(int bytesread, long microseconds, byte[]pcmdata,Map properties) {
      //bytesread imprime esto: bytes leidos-1
        //siempre se queda en -1
//microseconds imprime todo el tiempo que esta recorriendo la cancion en //microsegundos
        }

    @Override
    public void stateUpdated(BasicPlayerEvent bpe) {
    }
    @Override
    public void setController(BasicController bc) {

    }
```

Comment: Es la segunda vez que preguntas lo mismo. Aquí tienes un ejemplo - http://www.carballude.es/blog/2007/11/25/reproducir-musica-mp3-ogg-wav-en-java/comment-page-1/. Y aquí - http://lineadecodigo.com/java/reproducir-musica-por-java/ tienes un reproductor en el que te puedes apoyar.

Comment: ok , ya eh hecho eso por que crees que pregunto, eso no da el valor maximo de un jslider o process bar, solo da los microsegundos y el valor maximo de la cancion como la obtengo ese codigo no incluye eso. saludos

Comment: Sí que lo incluye. Mira en el segundo link que te he mandado, clase MP3seth, métodos opened y progress.

Comment: esto es lo que no entiendo se su pone que el parametro map debe imprimir audio.length.bytes pero no imprime eso imprime todo excepto esto que pide en el codigo  "map.containsKey("audio.length.bytes");"